# How to integrate braintree to iOS or Android app using flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm new to flutter. I've tried to build other hybrid apps using Ionic and cordova, we can use cordova plugins to add native functions.

In flutter, [there's pub packages](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/braintree) for braintree drop-in but it only supports android in the mean time.

Is it possible to use the iOS framework for Braintree together with Flutter?

I feel a little reluctant to switch to flutter since there's limited pub packages at the moment (especially for iOS platform). Simple app which requires only REST api calls seems to be more suitable to use flutter.

Comment: Reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pub you posted is discontinued. Please move to [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_braintree). Anyway, it's possible :)